# Javascript - Set timezone for script instance

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, flot

In a flot graph depending on the viewers timezone setting the points may or may not fall on vertical grid bars. Actually, only when the local timezone is set to utc the points are on the date bars. This does make sense as the time the sample refers to is not the same clock-time in all timezones.

However, for an application I want to turn this behavior off and display the same graph whatever the local machine's timezone is.

For that I thought I might be somehow able to set the timezone for the script to UTC (not changing the setting in Windows. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API documentation may be of help, scroll down to the section "Time series data". I think that this may help you to solve your problem:

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt

Comment: A RTFM type of answer, but fair enough.

Comment: @Majid Sorry it wasn't intended that way, the third paragraph seems to address your question.

Comment: I know, don't worry; I didn't find it insulting. Besides, the address you provided, did help. Thanks.

Comment: The documentation is pretty good once you find the section you need.